# Hyperplanes and loop parallelization

Tags: parallel-computing, loops

Is it possible for the hyperplane method for loop parallelization, to return more than one hyperplanes whose points are scheduled to be executed at the same time? In an example I studied (Shang & Fortes, 1991), I found nine hyperplanes, parallel each other and grouped in three sets, with the three hyperplanes of the first set to be scheduled at t=0, the three hyperplanes of the second set at t=1 and the three hyperplanes of the third set at time t=2. Is this correct?